# numpy first non zero value of vectors in a multi dimentional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 3dimensional numpy ndarray shaped (i,j,k) where each row is an array of multiple similarly sized vectors.

I would like to extract an (i,k) shaped array such that each element of the rows contains the first non-zero element of its group of "j" vectors

So basically, given an array such as:

```
[
  [
    [0 , 10 , 12 ,  0 , 4],
    [0 ,  0 , 13 ,  1 , 2],
    [12, 14 ,  1 , 12 , 8]
  ],

  [
    [5 , 17 , 12 ,  9 , 0],
    [0 ,  0 , 13 ,  1 , 0],
    [12, 14 ,  1 , 12 , 8]
  ],

  [
    [0 , 0  , 19 ,  0 , 9],
    [2 , 6  , 13 ,  0 , 2],
    [12, 14 ,  1 , 12 , 8]
  ]
]
```

Im looking to find something like:

```
[
  [12, 10, 12, 1, 4],
  [5 , 17, 12, 9, 8],
  [2 , 6, 19, 12, 9]
]
```

how to find the results efficiently?

```
import numpy as np

i,j,k = 3, 5, 10 #in real problem, these are pretty large
arr = np.random.randint(0, 10000, (i,j,k))
#????????
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple transpose https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html and advanced indexing https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing, the solution looks like this:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([
  [
    [0 , 10 , 12 ,  0 , 4],
    [0 ,  0 , 13 ,  1 , 2],
    [12, 14 ,  1 , 12 , 8]
  ],

  [
    [5 , 17 , 12 ,  9 , 0],
    [0 ,  0 , 13 ,  1 , 0],
    [12, 14 ,  1 , 12 , 8]
  ],

  [
    [0 , 0  , 19 ,  0 , 9],
    [2 , 6  , 13 ,  0 , 2],
    [12, 14 ,  1 , 12 , 8]
  ]
])

# swapping the 0 and 1 axes, to make the rest of the code easier
a = a.transpose((1, 0, 2))

# initialising result to zeroes, same shape as a single layer of the transposed a
result = np.zeros(a[0].shape, np.int32)

# one layer at a time
for layer in a:
    # as soon as result contains no more zeroes, done
    if len(result[result == 0]) == 0:
        break
    else:
        # replace all values of result that are zero
        # with values from the same location in layer
        result[result == 0] = layer[result == 0]

print(result)
```

Prints:

```
[[12 10 12  1  4]
 [ 5 17 12  9  8]
 [ 2  6 19 12  9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the most elegant way to do it, as I wrote it rather quickly on the fly. However, hopefully this is sufficient enough to get you started.

```py
def find_non_zero(lst):
  for num in lst:
    if num != 0:
      return num
```

First, we define a very simple helper function, `find_non_zero`, which receives a one-dimensional list as input and returns the first non-zero entry. This function is then used when we loop over each columns of the two-dimensional array in `arrays`, the three-dimensional input array provided.

```py
import numpy as np

arrays = [
  [
    [0 , 10 , 12 ,  0 , 4],
    [0 ,  0 , 13 ,  1 , 2],
    [12, 14 ,  1 , 12 , 8]
  ],

  [
    [5 , 17 , 12 ,  9 , 0],
    [0 ,  0 , 13 ,  1 , 0],
    [12, 14 ,  1 , 12 , 8]
  ],

  [
    [0 , 0  , 19 ,  0 , 9],
    [2 , 6  , 13 ,  0 , 2],
    [12, 14 ,  1 , 12 , 8]
  ]
]

final_result = []
for array in arrays:
  array = np.array(array).T  
  final_result.append([find_non_zero(col) for col in array])

print(final_result)
```

This yields the following output.

```
[[12, 10, 12, 1, 4], [5, 17, 12, 9, 8], [2, 6, 19, 12, 9]]
```

Numpy's `.T` tranpose operator comes in handy because it allows us to loop through two-dimensional arrays by columns, instead of the default row. For more information on the transpose operator, read the [official documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html).

I'd be happy to answer any additional questions you might have.

Comment: Depending on taste, OP might prefer a more Python-based solution to one that uses only `numpy`. As you might expect, it is a bit slower - I benchmarked both your solution and my `numpy` one using `timeit` and mine takes about 1.41 seconds for 100,000 iterations, while yours takes about 1.62. Low numbers, but small array of course.

Answer (score 0):

Use apply along axis and then apply the function nonzero and get first element in desired axis

```
np.apply_along_axis(lambda e: e[np.nonzero(e)][0], 1, x)
```

OR

```
np.apply_along_axis(lambda e: e[(e!=0).argmax()], 1, x)
```

Output

```
array([[12, 10, 12,  1,  4],
       [ 5, 17, 12,  9,  8],
       [ 2,  6, 19, 12,  9]])
```